# When resizing jqxWindow, window body width and height not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqxwidgets

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/odwm9neL/1/) to my problem. As you can see, divs displayed inside window have set width to 100%, and my goal si to foce this divs to automatically resize when I am manually resizing the window.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 5px solid #ccc
}
```

I was looking inside this element throught element inspection in chrome and I figured out, that *windowBody* div doesn't change its width and height and that is the problem. Does anyone know how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found out, that the problem was that you cannot declare maxWidth and maxHeight to 100% in jqxWindow declaration. You need to set absolute numbers. In my case worked setting them to max width of the screen.

```
$('#jqxwindow').jqxWindow({
height: 200,
width: 340,
minHeight: 100,
minWidth: 200,
maxHeight: screen.height,
maxWidth: screen.width,
isModal: true,
autoOpen: true,
resizable: true
```

});

here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1avscs3q/1/)